# JDBC UPDATE ERROR with MySQL - error code 1054

Tags: java, mysql, sql

this is the code

```
    PreparedStatement res1 = null;
    String insertUser = "INSERT INTO users (uid,firstname,lastname,score) VALUES (" + 
                                            this.getFbUid() + "," + 
                                            this.getFbFirstName() + "," + 
                                            this.getFbLastName() + ",0)";
    System.out.println(insertUser);
    try
    {
        res1 = connection.prepareStatement(insertUser);
        res1.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("executed query to db with the message" + res1);
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("setUserInDb: " +e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("error num: " +e.getErrorCode());
    }`
```

I'm getting `error code 1054`:

> Unknown column 'Alon' in 'field list' when trying to insert the line "INSERT INTO users (uid,firstname,lastname,score) VALUES (123456,Alon,xyz,0)

In the db I have table `users` with `varchar` columns `uid`, `firstname`, `lastname`, and `score`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Alon` seems or type varchar should be under `'`

Use Prepared statement rather

Comment: how to fix my String in java?

Comment: You didn't use it properly, See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just as Jigar pointed it out,

When u insert String values into the table you should use the values inside single or double quote(' or ").
Eg 'Hello',"Hello".

Comment: By all means use single quotes: `'Hello'`. Double quotes are for quoting object names. I know MySQL allows non-standard quoting, but there is no need to use it if the standard syntax is accepted as well.